# How to generate a static website using Vue3 without SSR?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue.js 3 app with components, vue-router, and pages (.vue files). When I use

`npm run build`

it generates a SPA `distr` folder. But I'd like to have a bandle of SEO-compatible static `.html` pages with assets (CSS, JS, images).

Also, I'd not like to use any SSR approach.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: This is called SSG and supported by the same platforms that provide SSR

Comment: You might want to look into Nuxtjs

Comment: I would not like to use any server-side approach...

Comment: @BohdanVorona You have to, otherwise this wouldn't be mentioned. This is not something that Vue alone does.